# Enumerate an object

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've created a class and put its objects into an Arraylist.

Here is the class:

```
Public Class ItemColl

    Public TBPid, PAid As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal _TBPid As Integer, ByVal _PAid As Integer)
        TBPid = _TBPid
        PAid = _PAid
    End Sub
End Class

Dim arrlst as new ArrayList

arrlst.Add(new ItemColl("1a","12"))

arrlst.Add(new ItemColl("1b","123"))

arrlst.Add(new ItemColl("1as","45"))

arrlst.Add(new ItemColl("1tr","67"))
```

I want is whenever I enumerate arraylist using its index, it would bring me the "ItemColl.TBPid" (please see below..)

```
For i As Integer = 0 To arrlst.Count - 1

     arrlst.item(i) //Here I need TBPid to be returned.

Next
```

I know I can override ToString(), but It would take a lot of time to change existing code with ".ToString()".

Comment: @[Umesh Kumawat] Always tag your question with the technology and language you are using (e.g. .NET, VB.NET in your case). The reason you didn't get any other responses is that you did not identify the technology, so .NET programmers did not know that your question was relevant to them. I tried to add the tags for you, but it was not approved.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class and then create a [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) of that type. With a strongly-typed list, you can then access the properties of the object like below:

```
Dim myList As New List(Of ItemColl)()
myList(0).PAid1 = 1
```

Of course, you can also cast each object in the ArrayList to an ItemColl:

```
TBPid= CType(arrlst(0), ItemColl).TBPid
```

But, I'd recommend using a List.